# Bixby Studio "Update failed" on Mac

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I get a "New Update Available" message when I open Bixby Studio. It's trying to upgrade from 6.5.0-rc.6439 to 6.6.1-r19c.6695 but returns the following message in the lower right corner of the interface:

"Update failed. Please re-install from bixbydevelopers.com"

I get this message even when I download the latest version off of the website mentioned in the error message. I'm using Mac Sierra v10.12.6.

Does anyone know how to successfully install the latest version of Bixby Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing version of your Bixby (from Applications) and download the new version from bixbydevelopers.com

Answer (score 0):

Solved by restarting my machine and installing an os update. Not sure which was the relevant fix. Thanks for the assistance BixbyDevSupportOne.